# Ruby on Rails shallow nesting resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to figure out the Ruby-on-Rails way of achieving shallow route nesting, that allows me to track the very top level resource.

Assume we have shallow nested routes set up as follows in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :article, shallow: true do
  resources :comments
end

resources :comments, shallow: true do
  resources :likes
end
```

How would you say redirect to `/articles/1/comments` from `comments/3/likes`, as `article_id` isn't available in the params so is the best way to place `article_id` in the session hash (when an article is shown via a callback in the controller?) and retrieve it that way? I've tried looking in the Rails Guide and while this explains shallow resource nesting it doesn't go beyond that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that an article has many comments and a comment belongs to an article you can access the article through the comment:

```
comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
comment.article_id
```

Comment: So as to avoid an additional query `comment.article_id` would be a better fit here.